# making templates in blender, questions about parenting

Tags: parent

I want to model a library full of bookcases, and i want to have a template of a bookcase so that when i edit one bookcase, all bookcases be effected. and whenever i want, i can break this relationship and make a single one bookcase 'unique'. 
in other words, i'm looking for a grouping method in blender, that every group can have same property and change in something change all members together..
i used the parenting system in blender. and it confuses me more.. and so i have problems with parenting itself.

1. when i want to copy one bookcase, and i press shift + D only parent object duplicates; and i have to select all children and parent together to duplicate them.
2. i can't assign a special point as origin of bookcase.

i'll be thankful if anyone help me :-)

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This seems like a job for [Linked Duplicates](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplication.html#linked-duplicates) and [Collection Instances](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/collection.html). Parenting is a different thing, it doens't keep object changes synced.